# How to make a Named Calculation in SSAS return the minimum date while execution

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, ssas, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have built a cube; and am not able to get the right results from it. Here is the issue I am facing.

I have a table in the DSV where I added a named calculated column. This column depends on two other columns:
Customer ID and date.
This calculated column must show the minimum date with respect to the customer. Here is the query I am using:

```
select customerID, min(date) mindate  from tableA where group by customerID
```

How do I build the query for the named calculation to get the minimum date of the customer?

```
customerID  mindate
656309  6/7/2013
10348   5/17/2013
687736  1/4/2013
130943  10/12/2012
657537  10/19/2012
428661  3/8/2013
9120    5/10/2013
5250    4/5/2013
681012  10/5/2012
37169   1/18/2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following expression

```
min(date) over(partition by customerID)
```

This may or may not work in a calculated column of the DSV. If it does not work as a calculated column, you could use this expression in a named query instead. To do this, right click on the table in the DSV, and select Replace table/with named query. This shows up a SQL select statement. In this, you can add the above expression, and it should work in any case.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying the named query now. Will update the results.